# Why this code works only in IE6, but in other versions red line breaks, or shows with full width?

Tags: html, css, margin

Why this code works only in IE6, but in other versions red line breaks, or shows with full width?  I want tha red line will be the same size as my editable text. But it works only in IE6. Why?

```
 <html>
        <header><!DOCTYPE html><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=6"></header>
        <body><p id='hr'></p>
        <pre contenteditable='true'>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 000
        </pre>
        </body>
        <style>
        * {
        margin:0;
        }

        #hr { 
        margin-top: 0.5em;
        padding: 0.5em;
        border-top: 4px dashed red;
        margin-right: -10000%;   // 
        }
        </style>
    </html>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? :O with that margin?

Comment: you html is not valid correct it first

Comment: IE6 what??? still caring about IE6??

Comment: This code works under IE6. I want that red line will be the same width as my pre text. But in all browser scrolling appears.

Comment: why the heck are you using IE6?..... upgrade ASAP - support for this has ceased almost a decade ago

Comment: Because I dont know how to make it in modern browsers.

Comment: Maybe explain what exactly you're trying to achieve and you can get some help - but as your question stands now it will be difficult to get help.

Comment: I want that red line will be from left side of browser till right side of browser. Overflow: hidden does not help me because if I scroll right red line disappears.